# How to set focus on a web element from a Java Bean

Tags: javascript, html, primefaces, focus

I'm using PrimeFaces, Java and JavaScript in a WebApp and the following problem occured:
I have two RadioButtons and when one of them gets selected, the focus disappears from the selected one. My goal is: The focus must remain there. The RadioButton selection triggers some value changes in the connected Java Bean and depending on these changes beneath the RadioButtons other Web Elements are loaded. So which website part is loaded is specified in the bean. But if these additional Web Elements are loaded, the whole page is updated and the focus that was located on the selected RadioButton disappears and you will find the focus at the page header again.
I'm using the  and the  elements in the HTML.

I tried following steps:

```
<t:radio for="radioOne" index="0" renderLogicalId="true"
    onclick="focus()" title="#{mybean.title}"/>
```

but it didn't work, the focus still disappears as soon as the complete page is loaded.

Is there a possibility to use a boolean attribute like focus or focused together with the  and get the values directly from the Java Bean? This could be something like this:

```
<t:radio for="radioOne" index="0" renderLogicalId="true" 
   title="#{mybean.title}" focused="#{mybean.selected}"/>
```

with boolean selected defined in the Bean. Unfortunately, I haven't found the focused attribute or something similar in combination with RadioButtons to set the focus from the Bean. Or, maybe you have a different solution that would fit to my case? Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are really using PrimeFaces have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml and https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/javaAPI?id=methods

Comment: The 'jsf' code above is not PrimeFaces but Tomahawk!